# Nested keys in mustache template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have following data structure:

```
var data = {
  labels: { name: "Name" },
  data: {
    name: "Layer 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Layer 1-1",
        children: [
          { name: "Layer 1-1-1" },
          { name: "Layer 1-1-2" }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Layer 1-2",
        children: [
          { name: "Layer 1-2-1" },
          { name: "Layer 1-2-2" }
        ]
      },
      { name: "Layer 1-3" }
    ]
  }
};
```

As you can see each layer can have it's own children. In this fiddle you can see, that the children are rendered multiple times: https://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/9xuLpnxp/

What do I have to change that the children are only rendered once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one to many `{{#children}}` tags, you should change the upper one to `{{#data}}`

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xuLpnxp/1/

Comment: I see, if there is no "children" it is trying to find one in the parent node. How can I prevent this? https://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/9xuLpnxp/2/ --> at the bottom there are still 3 rows too much.

Comment: That's an unexpected behavior. Anyways you can add `children` as an empty array like so: https://jsfiddle.net/9xuLpnxp/3/

Comment: Thank you very much